Is my method of training too much and will it get me and ideal lean muscle tone body?
I workout twice a day 5 days a week.
In the morning I’ll do a lift like chest day, leg day, etc. and then after my lift I always run a mile and go swimming for 20min moderately, and then sauna.
For my evening session I do cardio.
One day I’ll do skierg, row, run a mile and core and the next day I’ll do aero bike, push sled, run a mile and stair master. Then finish in the sauna.
I do have active recovery days on Fri and Sat where I just walk.
So it’s been 3 weeks and my diet is pretty much fasting the whole day and I break my fast at the end of the day with eggs and whatever meat I have to throw with it.
My weight was 200 starting and im 195 but I feel like I should be lower by now and my body tone is more like skinny fat then the lean muscle I would like to put on?
Any tips and suggestion would help so much! Thanks for making it this far if you read it!

So usually I crack 3 eggs open and mix in some cheese, with some chicken or ground beef. It’s about a plate full of food and have some fruit to go with it. I am probably starving myself and I know I shouldn’t but I just want to get back down to 170, not be skinny fat and lose the fat around my waist

Can you give us more details on your diet? It sounds like you are almost starving yourself (I can almost guarantee you aren't eating enough to sustain the activities) which will limit your progress.

In addition to what John says, age is a main factor when judging appropriate recovery times

It sounds to me like you're probably undereating for the amount of work that you're doing. I would start tracking every piece of food that you eat, weighing yourself daily, and using something like the MacroFactor app to track your actual caloric needs.

It's incredibly hard / impossible to lose more than five pounds per two weeks so your diary sounds fine so far?

You can do absolutely nothing until you PERFECTLY record every single thing that you eat each day.
You must be able to state precisely at any point during the day and at the end of each day, your calorie intake and your three macros intake.
Until you do that you're doomed.
Purely FWIW but it's irrelevant until you have perfect tracking recorded every day:

my diet is pretty much fasting the whole day and I break my fast at the end of the day with eggs and whatever meat I have to throw with it

Nothing could be worse.
As you know bodybuilders almost universally have 4, 5 or even 6 small meals a day.

some fruit

Fruit is utterly worthless, better to just eat chocolate or a coca-cola. It's a pure carb "treat" exactly like chocolate or candy. It has absolutely no nutritional value and is simply carbs.
You should be living on LEAFY GREEN VEGETABLES and meats, that's it. (Obviously never eat potatoes/carrots, unless your aim is to gain fat.)
Tt's irrelevant until you have perfect tracking recorded every day - good luck!
And I believe basically nutrition is off topic on this site anyway. But you can achieve nothing without step 1 - flawless recording and measurement of every atom of food you eat.  Good luck!

I am sorry but is this comment satire? Record every atom that you eat? Fruit is utterly worthless? Only eat potatoes if you aim to gain fat? Where are you getting this from?

There are many diffierent strong opinions on diet issues, MJB!  Fruit is very high in carbs. It's literally exactly like having a soft drink.  It's just "sugars". Potatoes, like bread or pasta, are incredibly high in carbs and it's precisely what you eat if you want to gain body fat.  It's totally noncontroversial that one of the keys to weight loss is proper recording of your macros intake every day.  All straightforward.

Regarding "where I get it from" ? it's now totally mainstream thinking.  (Hopefully you're not as old as me that you remember the rofl "food pyramid"  :) :) )  typical book https://www.amazon.com/Why-We-Get-Fat-About/dp/0307474259  great book btw!

The problem with Taube's book is two fold - He contradicts himself (The argument against the vilification of fat as a macronutrient but then discards another macro in carbs), and the logic doesn't correlate. A redditor says it best, "If I take oil out of my car it stops working so my car runs on oil and everyone who says gas is wrong". It's an ok read with slanted/cherry picked science. Calories in/calories out is basic thermodynamics, but the constitution of calories in can play a part.

Cheers John, I think there are plenty of problems with that particular book, and all books (I don't really read amazon reviews).  Body fat is simply caused by eating carbohydrates, which triggers your pancreas to cause glycerides (always constantly at all times present in your bloodstream) to pass in to fat cells in your body (becoming triglycerides). It's 100% true that calorie intake is key to body fat and it's 101% true that with 0 carbs, glycerides (always constantly at all times present in your bloodstream) to pass in to fat cells in your body (becoming triglycerides). One issue with calo

ries is that if you take (say) some twigs from a tree and do a bomb calorimeter measurement, it might have say 1000 calories.  if you or I eat it it will have .. on effect.  Same if you swallow gasoline (I did as a kid!) It's (nowadays) obvious that the bio-usage of calories depends on many things; such as the time of day consumed etc.  Anyway what the OP said did seem all over the place (why would he particularly eat fruit? why would he not eat until evening? etc)  Another great, old book is Life Without Bread, Lutz !!

Uhm... yeah, it doesn't really work the way you are thinking it does. And you did not swallow gasoline as a kid without serious health repercussions (Usually death). As far as eating in the evening, that is a common trend now with IF, all calories for a day in a small window of time.

without serious health repercussions (Usually death right, but no fat gain :)   Cheers

Fruit is not just sugar, it contains vitamins, minerals and fibers. Saying it's exactly the same as drinking soft drink is simply not true. But even if it was just sugar, there is nothing wrong with consuming carbs. Carbs are great, especially if you workout a lot. You get fat from consuming more calories than you burn, not from eating carbs.
